# Sorting on index of array mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where i have objects like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab212249a639865c58b744e"),
   "levels" : [ 
        {
            "levelId" : 0,
            "siteId" : "5a0ff11dc7bd083ea6a706b1",
            "title" : "Hospital Services"
        }, 
        {
            "levelId" : 1,
            "siteId" : "5a0ff220c7bd083ea6a706d0",
            "title" : "Reference Testing"
        }, 
        {
            "levelId" : 2,
            "siteId" : "5a0ff24fc7bd083ea6a706da",
            "title" : "Des Moines(Reference Testing)"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort on the title field of 2nd object of levels array e.g. levels.2.title
Currently my mongo query looks like:

```
db.getCollection('5aaf63a69a639865c58b2ab9').aggregate([
{$sort : {'levels.2.title':1}}
])
```

But it is not giving desired results.
Please help.

Comment: No its not!! I want to perform on the field in a specific object. Please analyse my question again.

Comment: Look at the record.  The value of title field in 2nd object of levels array is  **Des Moines(Reference Testing)**. 
I want to perform sorting on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query in 3.6.

```
db.col.aggregate({$sort:{"levels.2.title":1}});
```

This aggregation and find semantics are different in 3.4. More on [`jira`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19402) here

So

```
db.col.find().sort({"levels.2.title":1})
```

works as expected and aggregation sort is not working as expected.

Use below aggregation in 3.4.

Use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to project the second element in  [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep the computed value as the extra field in the document followed by [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) sort on field.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents) with exclusion to drop the sort field to get expected output.

```
db.col.aggregate([
 {"$addFields":{ "sort_element":{"$arrayElemAt":["$levels", 2]}}}, 
 {"$sort":{"sort_element.title":-1}},
 {"$project":{"sort_element":0}}
])
```

Also, You can use [`$let`](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) expression to output the title field directly in [`$addFields`](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage.

```
db.col.aggregate([
 {"$addFields":{ "sort_field":{"$let:{"vars":{"ele":{$arrayElemAt":["$levels", 2]}}, in:"$$ele.title"}}}},      
 {"$sort":{"sort_field":-1}},
 {"$project":{"sort_field":0}}
])
```

Comment: Is it possible to directly use {$sort : {'levels.2.title':1}}  ?

Comment: I didn't  test it now. Last time when I checked it didn't appear to work and can't find anything in the documentation. What happens when you try ?

Comment: It gives random data, not as per sorting

Comment: Alright I did quite a few tests. In 3.4 find sort i.e. `db.colname.find().sort({'levels.2.title':1})` works as expected where aggregation sort doesn't. In 3.6 both find and aggregation sort works as expected. Found [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19402) issue that back my tests. Updated question too with details